# What does little mean in "Little did I know this spelled the end of my career"?

Tags: word-usage

What does little mean in:

"Little did I know this spelled the end of my career"?

And is it the same thing as saying:

"I didn't know that this spelled the end of my career"?

Answer (score 1):

It means that

> ***I had no idea of*** or ***I was not even suspecting*** or ***I was totally unaware of*** the fact that this (event) spelled (marked) the end of my career.

It is in fact an idiomatic phrase, which [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/little-did-somebody-know-realize-think-etc) defines as

> little did somebody know/realize/think etc

`used to say that someone did not know or think that something would happen or was true`

> Little did I know that the course of my life was about to change.